# Calculate the percentage of image shown

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, tableview

I have a tableview(swift) and each row has one image. I would like to know how can I calculate the % of the image that is being shown (if I scroll, i can show for example only 50% of the image on the screen). I though about using top margin value to calculate it like this:

Images have a heigh of 400 px (or dpi's, etc). If the top margin is at any given time is like 100 px, that means the picture is beein shown. But if the top margin for that pic is -200, that means the pic is being shown at 50%... Is this the best practice? And if Yes, How Can I get the top margin from a picture? Thank you.

Comment: thats not how tableview works. youre confusing css.  i suggest you refer to UITableViewDelegate, specifically tableView:didScroll function.